# First item getting selected in listbox

Tags: java, swing, listbox, applet, jlist

I want to select items with keywords facebook and twitter in it. But the problem is the first item which is "aggregator" always gets selected. Can anyone tell me what is wrong in the code. Thanks.

```
   int j=0;
   jList1.setModel(listmodel);
   for (int i=0;i<listmodel.size();i++){

       if (listmodel.getElementAt(i).toString().indexOf("facebook")!=-1||listmodel.getElementAt(i).toString().indexOf("twitter")!=-1){
           a[j]=i;

           j++;
       }
   }


   jList1.setSelectedIndices(a);
```

Comment: `jList1.setSelectedIndex(j);` // ?

Comment: it overrides the previously selected items

Comment: This would have been so much easier if you cleared all the unnecessary code and reduced the finding of the right items to a simple and small method - what is `a`, what is `j`? All not mandatory for the problem.

Comment: `jList1.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionInterval(j, j);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select multiple elements, you can to use something like `JList#addSelectionInterval`, for example...

[image: List]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ListSelectionExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ListSelectionExample();
    }

    public ListSelectionExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
                model.addElement("Bananas on facebook");
                model.addElement("Bananas in pajamas");
                model.addElement("Teddies in space");
                model.addElement("Teddies on twitter");
                model.addElement("Rat on the moon");
                model.addElement("Cow over the moon");
                model.addElement("Facebook pandas");

                JList list = new JList(model);
                for (int index = 0; index < model.getSize(); index++) {
                    String text = model.getElementAt(index).toString().toLowerCase();
                    if (text.contains("facebook") || text.contains("twitter")) {
                        list.addSelectionInterval(index, index);
                    }
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(list));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your int-array, `a`, is too large. Since each slot in an int-array defaults to 0, that would mean that the 0-th item in the list most likely gets selected, since it will be featured in `a`, unless `a` is completely filled with values found in your for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely with the definition of your array a. You must have initialized it as

```
int[] a = new int[listmodel.size()];
```

which will default the array elements to 0. So after the for loop, your a will look something like [1, 2, 4, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0] and it causes first element to be selected as well since there is 0 in the array.

Solution is to intialize a with a number which is much greater than the number of list items you expect to have.